# Importing SwiftUI safeAreaInset into UIKit

Tags: swiftui, uikit, safearealayoutguide

`safeAreaInset(edge:alignment:spacing:content:)`:

> The modified view is inset by the height of content, from edge, with its safe area increased by the same amount.

It appears that SwiftUI's `safeAreaInset` is not imported into UIKit's safe area:

```
        ZStack {
            Color.black
            UIKitView()
        }
        .ignoresSafeArea(edges: .top)
        .safeAreaInset(edge: .top) {
            Text("TOP")
                .frame(minHeight: 200)
                .background(Color.cyan.opacity(0.5))
        }
```

In this example, both the `black` view and the `UIKitView` are laid out the same - they ignore both the `safeAreaInset:top` and the status bar.

The question is: how can the `UIKitView` learn about the safe area in play?

Consider the following:

```
struct UIKitView: UIViewControllerRepresentable {
    func makeUIViewController(context: Context) -> some UIViewController { ViewController() }
    func updateUIViewController(_ uiViewController: UIViewControllerType, context: Context) {}
    
    class ViewController: UIViewController {
        let bgView = UILabel()
        let safeView = UILabel()

        override func viewDidLoad() {
            bgView.backgroundColor = .red.withAlphaComponent(0.5)
            self.view.addSubview(bgView)
            safeView.backgroundColor = .green.withAlphaComponent(0.5)
            self.view.addSubview(safeView)
        }

        override func viewWillLayoutSubviews() {
            self.bgView.frame = self.view.bounds
            self.safeView.frame = self.view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.layoutFrame
        }
    }
}
```

We now see two layers generated by the `UIKitView`, one that represents the full frame of the view (`red`), and one that is limited to the known safe area (`green`).

What is clear now is that UIKit's safe area is constrained by the status bar, but NOT by the `safeAreaInset:top`. This is surprising – how can we learn about the full top safe area in play and correctly adjust the green view to accommodate the content placed manually above it?

[image: the resulting layout]

Comment: Not really clear... can you post an image of how you are ***expecting*** the views to layout?

Comment: @DonMag since the "TOP" view is in a `.safeAreaInset`, it should be creating an additional safe area inset that the `UIKitView` should be able to observe, consequently the green area is expected to stop short of the top view rather than continuing up to below the status bar. Notice that the green view observes the system safe area but not the safe area created by `safeAreaInset`.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you mixed up some concepts.

1. `ZStack` only stacks views on top of each other and does nothing to do with the `safeArea`.
2. You are performing environmental layout actions inside the prebuilt `UIViewController` functions with some static codes, like assigning the frame directly. So it will NOT update the UI as desired.

#### A better example explains itself:

Try the following to see what you are looking for:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            ZStack {
                Color.black
                UIKitView()
            }
            .ignoresSafeArea(edges: .top)
            .navigationTitle("Hello World")
        }
    }
}
```

[image: DemoImage]

By adding a `NavigationView` which respects the safe area, you can see that:

1. the `SwiftUI.Color.Black` goes beyond the `top` of the `SafeArea` below the `NavigationBar` but **NOT** below the `bottom` of the `SafeArea`
2. The `safeView`(the green one) is completely in the `safeArea` as you manually set the `safeAreaLayoutGuide.layoutFrame` on it, which is the *portion of your view that is unobscured by bars and other content*
3. The `bgView`(the red one) is sized and placed exactly like the `SwiftUI.Color.Black`. Because it is handled by the `SwiftUI` layout system.

#### So

- If you want to let the `SwiftUI` control the layout, go with the frame.
- If you want to ignore the `SwiftUI` layout and access the safe area of the `environment` (which can bث the status bar or any other bars like the navigation bar or even physical objects like the notch or the dynamic island), go with the internal view's `safeAreaLayoutGuide`.

Hope it explains the difference.

Comment: Ignoring `top` is correctly applied. Take a look at the **red** view and **black** color. Both of them are continued all the way up to the top edge of the device below both the navbar and the status bar

Comment: The question is not about whether ignoring top is correctly applied. Rather it is about why the environment's safe area includes only the status bar + nav bar, but not the `Text("TOP")` `safeAreaInset`. You have removed an element of the original problem and solved for that.

Comment: @lhunath did you ever figure this one out? I've encountered the same issue :(

Comment: @aehlke unfortunately not